# continuously run chrome extension in background when browser is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am new in Chrome extension, and from some examples, I have made an chrome extension.

in chrome extension's  I have written below code, for running background.js

**menifest.json**

```
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["src/bg/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
```

**backgroud.js**

```
 var config = {

  apiKey: "AIzaSyAqPnuP-EeU2WXhwJ_3Ks_er0KbTKE-BNg",
  authDomain: "hellofirebase-a1794.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://hellofirebase-a1794.firebaseio.com"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref().child('hellofirebase-a1894');

commentsRef.on('child_changed', function(data) {
  var opt = {
  type: "basic",
  title: "Primary Title",
  message: "Primary message to display   "+data.val(),
  iconUrl: "url_to_small_icon"
}
chrome.notifications.create("notifi"+1, opt, null);
});
```

**Firebase data structure** is looking like

```
hellofirebase-a1794
   |
   |
   -------betteryLevel : 13
```

So any value change in Firebase's Realtime database, I should get notification from chrome extension but nothing happen, any body please help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I sincerely hope that's not a real `apiKey`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a background page, you have to remove the `persistent: false` option. What you have now is [an event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), which will only run "when it's needed". A background page will run continuously, like you want.